# Array of objects with a particular styling in vue

Tags: vue.js

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app1',
  data: {
  objects:[
  {
    object: {
      title: 'C',
      author: 'Denis',
      publishedAt: '1960'
    }
  },
  {
    object: {
      title: 'Vue',
      author: 'Yet To Find',
      publishedAt: '2010'
    }
  }]}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.0/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app1">
  <ol>
    <div v-for="object in objects">
      {{index}} 
      <li v-for="value in object">
         {{value}}
      </li>
    </div>
  </ol>
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app1',
  data: {
  objects:[
  {
     
      title: 'C',
      author: 'Denis',
      publishedAt: '1960'
    
  },
  {
     
      title: 'Vue',
      author: 'Yet To Find',
      publishedAt: '2010'
    
  }]}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.0/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app1">
  <ol>
    <div v-for="object in objects">
      {{index}} 
      <li v-for="value in object">
         {{value}}
      </li>
    </div>
  </ol>
</div>
```

I am able to achieve these two variations. But I am trying to achieve the below

```
1.
  .C
  .Denis
  .1960
2.
  . 
  .
  .
```

How can I do it from what I have? I am trying to express bullet/number by Dot(.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    objects: [{
        title: 'C',
        author: 'Denis',
        publishedAt: '1960'
      },
      {
        title: 'Vue',
        author: 'Yet To Find',
        publishedAt: '2010'

      }
    ]
  }
})
```

```css
/*ignore - hide snippets console */

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.0/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <div v-for="(object, index) in objects">
      {{ index + 1 }}
      <li v-for="(value, key, index) in object" style="list-style-type:none">
        {{ index + 1 }}. {{ key }} = {{ value }}
      </li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Just for my clarification. Can I maintain 1,2,3 only at sub level?  Another question: Is it possible to show that as bullet also?

Comment: you would need change the dom, do the v-for on the <ol>

Comment: or dont use <ol> and make your own numbers with the index

Comment: Yes, I am able to do it. If I name the objects inside the array, how should I handle it? If the objects has nemes as in the first example, how to get the similar things?

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Actually it is a misunderstanding. I meant this `obj:{title, etc..}`. Here `obj` is an object name. It is part of the array.

Comment: your top top example would be `v-for="(value, key) in object.object"`

Comment: I just learnt that you can do `v-for="(value, key, index) in object"` over indexOf like my last edit, which is much nicer https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

Comment: If you preserved all of your edits, it would be great :) Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe so...

```
    <ul v-for="(object,index) in objects" 
 :key="index">
  {{index +1}}
       <li v-for="(prop, index) in object" :key="index">
        {{prop.author}}
        {{prop.title}}
        {{prop.publishedAt}}
      </li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: `prop.author` etc wont be defined if looping over the object